# what is Socket-IO's heartbeat mechanism?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I was reading on web sockets 'Ping/Pong'. web-sockets used this messages as heartbeat. 
since socket-IO internally uses web-sockets, my question is this,

does socket-IO use same 'ping/pong' messages as heartbeat or there is some other mechanism for that? 
if socket-IO uses `ping/pong` messages to check the connection, than what socket-IO uses for `XHR connection` and `flash-sockets`?

one more question,  as we know, we can't send ping messages from client-side, does socket-IO provide any implementation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io does ping/pong on all transports including polling, and this is done with its own heartbeat mechanism on [engine.io](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io) which socket.io is dependent on.
No ping/pong message of websocket is used at all.

Comment: can we send png message from client-end?

Comment: also, if I disable, heartbeat what consequences i'll face?

Comment: you can send ping from client like `socket.io.engine.ping()`, but usually shouldn't do this since it automatically happens anyway.

Comment: you may not be able to notice lost connection if disabled the heartbeat, so should not disable it without any reasons.

Comment: right thanks, actually i was confused between web-socket ping and socket-io ping. 
i thought we cannot send ping from client.

Comment: one more thing, can you please tell me way, how can i log heartbeat messages?